# How to gracefully shutdown any WSGI server?

Tags: python, http, wsgi

I've been experimenting with several WSGI servers and am unable to find a way for them to gracefully shut down. What I mean by graceful is that the server stops listen()'ing for new requests, but finishes processing all connections that have been accept()'ed. The server process then exits.

So far I have spent some time with FAPWS, Cherrypy, Tornado, and wsgiref. It seems like no matter what I do, some of the clients receive a "Connection reset by peer".

Can someone direct me to a WSGI server that handles this properly? Or know of a way to configure one of these servers to doing a clean shutdown? I think my next step is to mock up a simple http server that does what I want.

Answer (score 4):

HTTPd has the `graceful-stop` predicate for `-k` that will allow it to bring down any workers after they have completed their request. mod_wsgi is required to make it a WSGI container.